# Android Java -- Deserializing a file on the Android platform

Tags: java, android, file, serialization

I have a jave program that serializes files that are stored and read later. So I take the serialized files and try to read them in on my Android phone (working in Eclipse) using the exact same code I used in Java SE:

```
FileInputStream fis = null;
try {
    fis = new FileInputStream("iwastedahalfhouronthis.ser");
   } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
}
```

FileNotFoundException thrown. So ok, its probably not in the right place. So I place the file in every possible folder within the Eclipse project and try loading from those locations. No luck. Make sure the file name is correct, no luck. Use the fully qualified name given by eclipse: "/pleasehelp/src/com/imlosingit/iwastedahalfhouronthis.ser". No luck. Passed a file object into the FileInputStream. No luck. This was so trivially easy on Java. What's going on here?

-----------EDIT SOLUTION--------------------

```
        Data data = null; //object to be deserialized
        InputStream is = null;
        ObjectInputStream ois=null;
        AssetManager assets = getAssets();
        is = assets.open("fff.ser");
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(is);
        data = (com.data.Data) ois.readObject();
```

Comment: Have you tried printing out where the file is stored when you created it?

Comment: It isn't clear if you're creating the files with Android code on your phone, if you're packaging them with the apk or downloading using HTTP etc etc. Explain further - there are numerous places you can store files on an Android device and knowing 'how' you create and store them might help somebody give you a method of finding them.

Comment: The files were created on my laptop, imported into an eclipse project in a variety of locations (a dir i created alongside the src dir, in the src dir) then ran the program on my smartphone using the debugger. I intend for all the serialized files to be stored w/in the apk.

Comment: To whomever -- why does this warrent a close?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out some of the getters in [`Context`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html). Try saving the files to the cache folder, or if they're going to be large files, you may want to try an external directory (e.g. SD Card).

```
File dir = getCacheDir();
//do stuff, saving the file in this directory

FileInputStream fis = null;
try {
    fis = new FileInputStream(new File(dir, "iwastedhalfhouronthis.ser"));
} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
}
```

EDIT: After reading your comment, I'd suggest storing your serialized files under `/assets`. Then you can use AssetManager to retrieve these:

```
AssetManager assets = getAssets();
AssetFileDescriptor afd = assets.openFd("iwastedhalfhouronthis.ser");
FileInputStream fis = afd.createInputStream();
```

EDIT: One more thing to try. Put the .ser file in a new folder called `/raw` (you'll have to  create it manually), and try this:

```
Resources res = getResources();
//might need "R.raw.iwastedhalfhouronthis.ser" but I don't think so.
AssetFileDescriptor afd = res.openRawResourceFd(R.raw.iwastedhalfhouronthis);
FileInputStream fis = afd.createInputStream();
```

Comment: That works with a text file, so big improvement just get something to stream in. Not working for serialized file. Any advice? Thanks guy.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no experience with serialized files, but I wouldn't see why it should cause a problem. By "not working", do you get an exception? Incorrect data? What exactly?

Comment: assets.openFd("text.txt") returns a file, whereas assets.openFd("serial.ser") returns null. I've tested the serialized file and it works on my desktop java program. I have a feeling this is going to take me all day to find a two line solution.

Comment: Thanks dude. Your first solution was really close.

Answer (score 2):

Take a [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3185559/android-cant-write-to-files-dir-but-can-in-package-dir) - the serialized file should go to `/data/data/APP_PACKAGE/iwastedahalfhouronthis.ser`.

Answer (score 1):

Put the files in the /res/assets directory. You can then use Context.getAssets() to return an AssetManager instance to handle the files in the assets directory.

Answer (score 0):

I think we have the similar case where a javaSe app generates a binary file and the android has to read it.

This is how I did it.
Place the file first in res/raw

```
 Resources res = getResources();
 InputStream is = res.openRawResource(R.raw.kasalvage);
 ObjectInputStream ois =new ObjectInputStream(is);
 //Blueprint is my custom object
 bp = (BlueprintMap)ois.readObject();
 Toast.makeText(this, bp.getTitle(), 2000).show();
```

I had to make a Jar library that contained the BlueprintMap class model and imported it to the projects both the Desktop app and the android app and it eliminated the ClassNotFoundException.
I hope this helps